# Find something(min/max/unique) for path between u and v node in a graph for every query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/hiring/sap-labs-java-hiring-challenge/algorithm/micro-and-internship-10/description/

In query based questions, like above, where we have to find path between two nodes every time and perform some operation on the path, what should be the approach? I have tried DFS, but it's giving run time error as well as Time limit Exceeded.

DFS algorithm

Comment: Logging is necessary to access your link, you should rephrase your question.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not require access to outside resources. (Images stored on hosting services are an obvious exception.) Please add the relevant parts from your link required to understand and answer your question. Please also post your attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First let's solve the problem using normal dfs for each query. What we need is a boolean array `V` of length 100 (since the values on each node can't exceed 100) and as we traversing each node if `V[a[u]]` (where `u` is the current node) is `0` set it to `1` and increment the answer.

Now to solve a similar problem like finding a min edge between two nodes we need to use **sparse table** which is also used to find **LCA**, if you dont know what a sparse table is I recommend you read about it here https://www.hackerrank.com/topics/lowest-common-ancestor (the third part). Briefly it's a way to find LCA in `O(log n)` with `O(nlogn)` pre-processing.

If we take 2 nodes `u` and `v` and we want to find the min weight in the path it's equivalent to finding the min of the min weight from `u` to `LCA(u,v)` and and the min weight from `v` to `LCA(u,v)`.

How is that useful ? using sparse table, instead of just saving where a node go to if it makes a jump of height `h` we also save the min edge on the path then we can simply answer each query with `O(log n)` complexity.

The same implies to this problem but instead of storing the min value we've got a boolean array as I explained in the first approach, where the `i-th` value is `1` if there is an edge of weight `i` when we make a jump of height `h` and `0` otherwise. Using this array you should be able to answer each query.

this solution makes `100 * log n` operations when answering a query since we're iterating through the boolean array.